# Magento 2 : Override layout.xml File Within Custom Module

Tags: magento2, module, layout, overrides

Looking at the Magento 2 docs, you can override a base/core layout.xml file - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Is it possible, to overide within a module rather than theme?

Alternatively, is it possible to bundle a theme within a module and extend that (and multiple other themes from multiple other modules) from the main website theme?

Answer (score -1):

It is the same as with with theme layout but you have copy **layout xml file** in your **layout directory**.

```
Namespace/Moduelname/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Comment: If I put the xml file in Namespace/Moduelname/view/frontend/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view.xml it does not override it. I can extend the layout by placing it in the path you suggested, but I am looking for an override NOT extend

Comment: Won't that just extend the XML?

Comment: @BenCrook it's extend the layout

Answer (score -1):

When load, Magento will load all the XML files which have same name and merge them. If you want to override, you have to remove all the element of core layout in you XML file.Use this:

```
<referenceContainer name="container-name" remove="true"/>//with container
<referenceBlock name="block-name" remove="true"/>//with block
```